# A column with Check constraint that accepts only caps A to caps Z

Tags: sql, oracle11g, check-constraints

I have a column of `varchar2(30)` with `not null` and `check constraint`.

My problem is, I want that column to accept only caps A to caps Z only by using check constraint.  How do I do this?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CONSTRAINT check_column_name CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(column-name, '^[A-Z]+$'));
```

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cf5c/1) exemplifying it.